# How to create an exception for hashtags in spacy?

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I have a problem where I have to split and lemmatize a document of strings using the default spacy behavior. The exception from the default behavior would be to not split tokens that are starting with hashes.

I have the following code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer


class Vectorizer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
        self.nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(r"#\S+", [{"ORTH": "#"}])

    def tokenize(self, data):
        # tokenize and lemmatize the documents
        lemmatized_tokens = []
        for document in data:
            doc = self.nlp(document)
            tokens = [token.lemma_ for token in doc]
            lemmatized_tokens.append(tokens)
        return lemmatized_tokens
```

I would expect this code to do the default spacy behavior, except when a token starts with a hash. However it outputs the following:

```
Vectorizer().tokenize(
    ["#hashtag this is a test, How does this WORK"])
```

For this code it outputs:

[['#', 'hashtag', 'this', 'be', 'a', 'test', ',', 'how', 'do', 'this', 'work']]

Which is not what I expected, the hashes are still seen as individual tokens which I do not want.

Answer (score 2):

A special case isn't what you need here - instead what you want is to remove a prefix that can be split off. A hashtag is like a bracket in that sense.

Following [an example](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizer-additions) from the docs:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")

prefixes = list(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)
prefixes.remove("#")
prefix_regex = spacy.util.compile_prefix_regex(prefixes)
nlp.tokenizer.prefix_search = prefix_regex.search

for tok in nlp("#hashtag ok"):
    print(tok)
```